# VB.NET: Get namespace of an assembly

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

I have got an embedded ressource (included in the executing assembly) and can get this with the following command:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<MyNamespace>.<File>")
```

If the namespace of the assembly changes I have to find all places where  is contained in the strings. To avoid this I'd like to get the namespace dynamically. Is there a possibility to get the namespace of an assembly or have I to use fixed values?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: You could use Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().  Now you have two problems, best to not write code that tries to solve a problem that is as yet only imagined.  Using a single const in your code is the simple solution.

Comment: A const was an idea I also have ;-) This seems to be the simplest solution. Then I will use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a dummy type within that namespace, and extract the namespace from that type:

```
public class TestType
{
}

var obj = new TestType();
var ns = obj.GetType().Namespace;
```

EDIT: of course this is a good solution if the namespace is part of your existing assembly and you have access to the source of it

Comment: That works great. In my case I don't need the dummy type because I can use the same class in that the above code is executed. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more generic and globally applicable to use Me.GetType().Namespace in any method in your class code?

Comment: Me.GetType().Namespace returns the namespace of current class. Different classes can have different namespaces. It is often the case that we want to get the namespace of another  class/assembly which is different.